# contact.id token not working in email

Tags: civimail, tokens

I used to have no problem having a link in an email like

...signup.php/reply={contact.id}

Today the token does not fill with the recipient's id.

The same email has

Dear {contact.first_name},

that works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If the link has
{contact.contact_id}
rather than what the token dropdown gives {contact.id}
The link fills as before.

If you look at old email that worked now get the message:
"Deprecated: Deprecated function CRM_Utils_Token::getTokenDetails, use If you hit this in mailing code you should use flexmailer - otherwise use the token processor. in /home/mastersu/public_html/wp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 1087"

Anybody know what we should do now?

Comment: Do you have flexmailer enabled? If not then enable it.